# J2ME architecture

Tags: java-me

I was reading about the J2ME architecture where it was written that there are 3 layers

> 1) Configuration Layer: It has JVM and interacts with the OS
>   2) Profile layer: Minimum set of API's for small device
>   3) MIDP layer: Contains Java API's

The book is [J2ME: The Complete Reference](http://www.amazon.com/J2ME-Complete-Reference-James-Keogh/product-reviews/0072227109)

QUESTIONS

1) Do every phone have an OS? If not what is the first layer doing in that case?
2) What is API's for small device?
3) MIDP is itself a profile which means it should be at second layer then how come it is at third layer?

Comment: where did you read what you describe?

Comment: Complete Reference book. Is there something wrong?

Comment: do you mean _J2ME: The Complete Reference_ by James Keogh? http://www.amazon.com/J2ME-Complete-Reference-James-Keogh/product-reviews/0072227109

Comment: well, book author doesn't look quite credible. Book reviews at Amazon seem to be not very favorable. As far as I can tell, stuff like that would be better to study from Oracle/Sun SDN: http://developers.sun.com/mobility/getstart/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conﬁgurations and proﬁles are the main elements that comprise J2ME’s modular design. These two elements enable support for the plethora of devices that 
J2ME supports.
A J2ME conﬁguration deﬁnes a minimum Java platform for a family of devices. 
Members of a given family all have similar requirements for memory and processing power.

**A conﬁguration is really a speciﬁcation that identiﬁes the systemlevel facilities available, such as a 
set of Java language features,
the characteristics and features of the virtual machine present,
and the minimum Java libraries that are supported.**

Software developers can expect a certain level of system support 
to be available for a family of devices that uses a particular conﬁguration.

A conﬁguration also speciﬁes a minimum set of features for a category of devices. 
Device manufacturers implement proﬁles to provide a real platform for a family 
of devices that have the capabilities that a given conﬁguration speciﬁes.
The other J2ME building block, the proﬁle, speciﬁes the application-level interface 
for a particular class of devices. A proﬁle implementation consists of a set of Java 
class libraries that provide this application-level interface. Thus, a proﬁle theoretically could specify all kinds of functionality and services.

This is not the intention of its creators, however. The creators of J2ME intend that 
a proﬁle should address the needs of a speciﬁc device category or vertical market 
pertaining to that device category. The idea is not to place a plethora of unrelated 
application level features in a proﬁle. Rather, the main goal is to guarantee interoperability—which doesn’t necessarily imply compatibility between different manufacturers’ implementations—between all devices of the same category or vertical 
market family to deﬁne a standard platform for Java application development.

For example, a proﬁle might support a network communication facility for the 
popular Short Message Service (SMS) standard widely used by mobile phones. 
Because the SMS standard is a ubiquitous feature of mobile telephony, it makes 
sense to deﬁne this service in a proﬁle that targets mobile phones, rather than to 
build it into a conﬁguration.

A proﬁle is implemented on top of a conﬁguration, one step closer to the implementation of real-world applications.

Typically, **a proﬁle includes libraries that are 
more speciﬁc to the characteristics of the category of devices they represent than 
are the libraries that comprise conﬁgurations.**

Applications are then built on top 
of the conﬁguration and proﬁle; they can use only the class libraries provided by 
these two lower-level speciﬁcations. Proﬁles can be built on top of one another. A 
J2ME platform implementation, however, can contain only one conﬁguration.

Figure 1.1 shows the conceptual layers that comprise the J2ME platform.

[image]

So far, these notions of conﬁgurations, proﬁles, and platform deﬁnitions is somewhat abstract. The next section gives you a more concrete description of the characteristics of actual environments.
Conﬁgurations and Proﬁles
A conﬁguration speciﬁes three basic elements:

- • a set of Java programming language features

  • a set of Java virtual machine features

  • a set of supported Java libraries and application programming
  interfaces (APIs)

Hope this will help you to understand J2ME Architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer....But as per the diagram above in J2ME architecture there are 2 layers(neglecting the OS and hardware since it belongs to device) i.e. Configuration and Profile and as far as the Java application is concerned it is the developer who makes it?

Comment: Yes,Java Application which developed by developer, Where developer uses only the class libraries provided by these two lower-level speciﬁcations(conﬁguration and proﬁle).

Answer (score 1):

Answers are as follows,

1. Yes, Every Phone has Operating System.
2. API's for small device(mobile phone) is depends on the oprating system loaded into the device.
3. MIDP is made up of Libraries, this is the reason it is on third layer as shown in the picture in above answer of Sajid.

Comment: Thanks but MIDP is profile and in diagram it is second layer. I am newbie so please bear me.